# How to Decrease Query Compile Time in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have seen that the first time query execution taking longer time to execute but second execution takes less time, seems like query compile time is taking longer time at first, can we do anything here which will increase the performance of compile time ?

Scenario:

enable_result_cache_for_session is off

We have SLA defined to execute specific query is 15 seconds but when run for the first time it is taking 33 seconds to compile and run the query that time SLA is miss but subsequent run took 10 seconds which is SLA hit.

Q: How do I tune this part ? How do I make sure this does not happens ?

Do we have any database configuration parameter for the same?

Comment: While some of the speed improvement might be due to query compilation, part of the speed improvement might also be due to cached data. You might also want to try and improve the speed of the actual query itself through appropriate use of `DISTKEY`, `SORTKEY` and compression types -- this may improve the query beyond so that it runs better in _both_ situations.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I will update my question to make it more understandable

Comment: There is no magic configuration setting that says "make compilation faster". You will either need to run the query ahead of time (eg schedule it to run at particular times), or you will need to improve the performance of the query. You have provided no information about your table structure or the query, so it is not possible for us to recommend any particular changes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question says ***compile time*** but I understand that you are interested in improving the ***execution time***, right?

For sure the John Rotenstein comment makes total sense, to improve the Redshift execution query time you need to understand the RS architecture and how to distribute your data in the best way you can to improve the queries time.

You will need to understand the DISTKEY and SORTKEY

Useful links
Redshift Architecture
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_high_level_system_architecture.html
https://medium.com/@dpazetojr/redshift-architecture-basics-4aae5068b8e3

Redshift Distribuition Styles
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html
https://medium.com/@dpazetojr/redshift-distkey-and-sortkey-d247b01b01f6

**UPDATE 1:**
In order you tune query and know how/when use DISTKEY and SORTKEY, we can start using the EXPLAIN command in the query you run and based on that act more precisely.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXPLAIN.html
https://dev.to/ronsoak/the-r-a-g-redshift-analyst-guide-understanding-the-query-plan-explain-360d

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, RedShift caches compiled code in global cache. As the compilation is translating c++ into native code, I think as a user there is not too much we can do to reduce the compilation time.
If Redshift use LLVM compiler the compilation time can be reduced.
see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_challenges_achieving_high_performance_queries.html#compiled-code